# Can't write documents with Firestore and React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use Firestore within my React Native app. So far, I couldnt reach a write/add document operation. I don't know where is the mistake? I don't recieve any error message and when I check y Firestore Database nothing is there.

This is my code:

**api/index.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, setDoc, addDoc,doc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

const addUser =  () => { setDoc(doc(db, "users", "mario"), {
  employment: "plumber",
  outfitColor: "red",
  specialAttack: "fireball"
});}


export { db,addUser };
```

screens/auth/sign.up

```
import React from "react";
import { ... } from "react-native";
import { sendEmailVerification,getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { addUser } from "../../api/index";

export class SignUpScreen extends React.Component {

    _handleCreateUser = async () => {
    
    const auth = getAuth();

    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth,this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then((userCredentials) => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        sendEmailVerification(user)
        addUser()
        auth.signOut()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this._handleNotification(error.message,'error')
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this._handleCreateUser}
          >
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              {global.loc.getTranslation("CreateNewUserButton")}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write to Firestore collection is asynchronous operation,let refactor `addUser` function

```
const addUser = async () => {
  try {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", "mario"), {
      employment: "plumber",
      outfitColor: "red",
      specialAttack: "fireball",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

and also `_handleCreateUser`

```js
export class SignUpScreen extends React.Component {
  _handleCreateUser = async () => {
    try {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const userCredentials = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        this.state.email,
        this.state.password
      );
      const user = userCredentials.user;
      await sendEmailVerification(user);
      await addUser();
      await auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      this._handleNotification(error.message, "error");
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleCreateUser}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              {global.loc.getTranslation("CreateNewUserButton")}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I still don't get why u need two async/await, before calling addUser and declareing addUser function.

Comment: It's a little bit confusing from someone who's familiar with chaining promises, but it's required to make sure that all promises successfully resolved or rejected.

Comment: Could you provide some documentation about it?